# Python ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib

Tags: python, ssl, pyspark, request, ssl-certificate

I am trying to call an api using python request with a certificate, but getting error,

ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3554)
Steps I followed
--> Stored my certificate to jenkins credentials
--> In jenkins I am copying that to my server, as application is on-prem
--> Then in my python script I am able to read that certificate, [ my certificate is in .cer format ]

```
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
certificate_file_path = os.path.join(script_directory, 'hawkeyeCertificate.cer')
response = requests.get(is_epp_api_end_point, headers=access_token, params=params, cert=(certificate_file_path, None))
```

Comment: *"my certificate is in .cer format "* - there is no such thing. There is PEM, DER, PKCS#8 (PFX), ... - ".cer" is just a file name suffix, not a format. It does not imply anything about the actual format inside.  Python expects proper PEM, which you don't seem to provide. Apart from that you need to specify the private key for your client certificate - which you don't seem to provide either (maybe its in your certificate file, maybe not).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, If you have .cer file, instead of passing it in the cert= param, pass that cer file in verify,

Instead of this,

```
response = requests.get(is_epp_api_end_point, headers=access_token, params=params, cert=(certificate_file_path, None))
```

Use this,

```
response = requests.get(is_epp_api_end_point, headers=access_token, params=params, verify= 'my_certificate.cer')
```